# Complex tree model and ViewModel using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I've a design issue with MVVM.

I want to make a Generic Model in a tree way (simplified):

```
public class ModelElement : ViewModelBase, IModelElement
{
    private ValueWarper ValueProperty;
    public ValueWarper Value
    {
        get { return ValueProperty; }
        set { ValueProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value); }
     }

      private ObservableCollection<IModelElement> ChildrenProperty;
      public ObservableCollection<IModelElement> Children
      {
        get { return ChildrenProperty; }
        set { ChildrenProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Children); }
      }

      private IModelElement ParentProperty;
      public IModelElement Parent
      {
          get { return ParentProperty; }
          set { ParentProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Parent); }
      }
}
```

Then In my ViewModel I have this property:

```
private ObservableCollection<IModelElement> ListElementProperty;
public ObservableCollection<IModelElement> ListElement
{
    get { return ListElementProperty; }
    set { ListElementProperty= value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListElement);}
}
```

Each `ModelElement` is binding on a control in the view (a `TextBox`, a `DatePicker`, a `Label` etc...)

The binding in the view is totally awful and I want to change this. I know that's not a viable solution.

So now there are some ways to achieve what I want:
Flatten the model by wrapping it in the ViewModel: Ok... But what if I've 10 levels? I've to build 10 viewModels?...

Build something like a `ObservableDictionnary` instead of `ObservableCollection` for the children of my `ModelElement`, it will bit more understandable in the binding view if the keys are well-chosen strings.

Other ways? Any thought? My aim is to make the binding in the view not too tedious, keep it simple and flexible...

Comment: If you are trying to use a tree model, you want to bind it to a tree control in wpf. The tree control handles hierarchical binding very well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I might explain myself badly. I don't want to make a tree in the view. It's just my model which is build this way.
For example: A category  contains section which contains comments etc... 
All of these elements must be in a form in the view, attached to a control which can be a textbox, or a DatePicker etc... Not a Tree Control.

Comment: Ok, in that case you probably want to build some datatemplates for each type, and have explicitly typed classes so that the datetemplate can implicitly bind to objects of that type. For example you know a Category has sections, so your Category datatemplate has specific controls for displaying its data and also a list control of some sort of sections, and the same for sections, etc.. for your hierarchy

Comment: Ok so you think that it's not possible to  make a generic class for the model like I did? 
I've to build a categoryModel, a reviewModel etc? So if i've 50 levels, i've to build 50 Model classes? 
And if each model have 10 fields, i've to add 10 fields in the ViewModel for each of the 50 Model?
Even if every classes have about the same kind? 
I mean maybe some of them will have 20 fields, but that's why i wanted to put them into a list... But beside that, the only difference between element is that in the ValueWarper, it will be either DateTime, string or Double... That's all =x

Comment: How would the code know what to display for any given class? You need to have some explicit definitions. With your example say you have a Category class with Sections, but category's values needs radio buttons and Sections needs comboboxes. If everything is generic how does the XAML know which to use if all it gets is a IModelElement with some Generic Value. You can use generics but some things need to be explicit so you can template things of that type

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with this. 
So I can build an ObservableDictionnary, with a string key (well-chosen) to ease the binding into the view.
So instead of having  
 `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyFirstCategory.Children[0].Value}"/>`

I'll have:
  `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyFirstCategory.Children['TheKeyOfThePropertyINeed'].Value}"/>`
 Better for understanding but not good enough I think. 
 The point is to not create a lot of ViewModels with a lot of properties which would be hard to maintain...

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your intended purpose is. You mention having 50 levels. I can't imagine something not intended for a tree to have 50 levels. Also you can style the Tree control so it isn't just some dropdown. I really think for what you are talking about a Tree control is the best option. Also there is nothing wrong with having many single purpose classes if each one is distinct from the others.

Comment: All of theses models objects will be related in the database... I won't have 50 levels but it can be 5 or 6...
The content of all of these elements are modifiable and will be displayed as DatePicker, Textbox, numericInput in a form.
Therefore the treeview control is a no go.
So you think I've to build a class for every level, and flatten their children...
I'd prefer the ObservableDictionnary way... But it's not optimal too...

Comment: I think it's just a bit unclear (at least to me) exactly what you are trying to accomplish and why so I can't say the best way to go about it. I would just suggest looking into what DataTemplates can do and see if maybe that helps you. You may only need to define a few "leaf" classes and still be able to have the generic structure you have now. DataTemplates can determine the "subtypes" even if you pass it an interface